# What's Wrong in this pipeline script

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, devops, pipeline

I wanted to check the output of my python execution but I am getting this error:

> Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/mtaghadosi/Jenkins-Project-Test.git
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
> startup failed:
> WorkflowScript: 20: Expected a step @ line 20, column 18.

```
        stage('run-python'){
            status=bat(returnStdout: true, script: 'python ./codes/sample.py')
            steps{
                echo "$NAME"
                echo "$status"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fount the solution:

```
    stage('run-python'){
        steps{
            script {
                    output = bat (returnStdout: true, script: '@python ./codes/sample.py')
                    echo "$output"
                    if ("$output".contains('Hello')) {
                        echo 'Python Command Executed Successfully.'
                    }  else {
                        echo 'There is an error in python code, please check.'
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```